# Programmatically Create Template in Certificate Authority

Tags: c#, certificate

I need to create Programmatically certificate's template on CA using c# (you can check the template by typing certtmpl.msc if you have server OS)

the created template should has some specific configuration like "CA certificate manager Approval"

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the export/import APIs

http://blogs.technet.com/b/pki/archive/2009/09/26/introducing-certificate-template-api.aspx?Redirected=true

a7la Jaafar

Comment: the url is not available. but this one: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/core-infrastructure-and-security/introducing-certificate-template-api/ba-p/1128560